# automatic testing for CSS?

Tags: html, css, testing, cross-browser, automated-tests

Is there any tool that allows you to automatically test page under different browser and make sure CSS looks good?

P.S. I know it sounds impossible, but maybe there are some solutions (like taking screenshots and comparing them)

Comment: the trouble is that "looks good in all browsers" is subjective. You'll never get it pixel-perfect in all browsers, even if the CSS is 100% perfect because they all have different font and graphic rendering routines. You can certainly compare them, but how do you do it automatically? How do you tell an automated program which of the subtle differences are acceptable and what aren't? The only real way to get visual acceptance is to look at the site manually.

Comment: @Spudley you could for example extract rectangles (like SO's "Ask Question" button) and check if size if similar(size difference should not be more than 20px), if first letter is not touching the wall (is at least 5px from wall), etc. I think its possible, but not easy to do ;) looking good = not looking bad

Answer (score 2):

https://browserlab.adobe.com/ - adobe id is needed, but it's free.

and

http://netrenderer.com - just for IE.

Both only take screenshots, but with a very little delay.

also for ie http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage - It's still in alpha state so it can only be trusted to a point.

Personally though, I pretty much have every browser in my comp so I can test things out in the actual browser. Plus all of the major ones do have web dev tools so.. if you can download all the browsers that's a good choice.

And I really just test all around functionality. For example if text is little different in some browsers then so be it, as long as it doesn't get cut or anything.

Comment: +1 for Adobe BrowserLab.  Just played around with it and it's pretty cool - check out the onion skin comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Tried BrowserStack? http://www.browserstack.com/

There was some other site I occasionally used to use that returned a set of images, but I can't remember what it was, and it wasn't always accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://browsershots.org/ to create screenshots on all types of devices and browsers. This might be what you are looking for.